# Use of Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

Let $c>0$ a fixed parameter.

By using the Taylor's series I want to prove that there exists a constante $A>0$ which does not depend on $c$ such that  $$\ln\left(1-\frac{2f(t)}{f(t)+g(t)}\right)\ge A(\frac{c+1}{4})t^3$$ for all $t\le \frac{1}{\sqrt c}$

where for all $t>0$:

\begin{align}
f(t) & =\frac{1-\cos(t\sqrt{c})}{c}-(\cosh(t)-1) \\[10pt]
g(t) & =\frac{\sin(t\sqrt{c})}{\sqrt{c}}+\sinh(t)
\end{align}

This is what i wrote:
for all $t\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}$

$$sin(t\sqrt{c})=t\sqrt{c}-\frac{(t\sqrt{c})^3}{3!}+..+(-1)^n\frac{(t\sqrt{c})^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+O((t\sqrt{c})^{2n+3})$$ for all $t\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}$
for all $t\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}$

$$cos(t\sqrt{c})=1-\frac{(t\sqrt{c})^2}{2!}+..+(-1)^n\frac{(t\sqrt{c})^{2n}}{(2n)!}+O((t\sqrt{c})^{2n+1})$$ 
$$\cosh(t)=1+\frac{t^2}{2!}+..+\frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}+O(t^{2n+1})$$

$$\sinh(t)=1+\frac{t^3}{3!}+..+\frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+O(t^{2n+3})$$

But i don't know how to find the result.

Answer (score 0):

*I am not sure how much this could help you.*

Using

$$f(t)  =\frac{1-\cos(t\sqrt{c})}{c}-(\cosh(t)-1) $$
$$g(t)  =\frac{\sin(t\sqrt{c})}{\sqrt{c}}+\sinh(t)$$ truncated Taylor series built around $t=0$ are
$$f(t)=-\frac{1}{24} (c+1) t^4+\frac{1}{720} \left(c^2-1\right)
   t^6-\frac{\left(c^3+1\right)}{40320} t^8+O\left(t^{10}\right)$$
$$g(t)=2 t+\frac{1}{6} (1-c) t^3+\frac{1}{120} \left(c^2+1\right)
   t^5+\frac{\left(1-c^3\right)}{5040} t^7+\frac{\left(c^4+1\right)
   }{362880}t^9+O\left(t^{10}\right)$$ making
$$\frac{2f(t)}{f(t)+g(t)}=-\frac{1}{24} (c+1) t^3+\frac{1}{480} \left(1-c^2\right) t^5-\frac{(c+1)^2
   }{1152}t^6-\frac{(c+1) (c^2-15c+1) }{40320}t^7-\frac{(c-1)
   (c+1)^2 }{11520}t^8+O\left(t^9\right)$$
$$\log\left(1-\frac{2f(t)}{f(t)+g(t)}\right)=\frac{1}{24} (c+1) t^3+\frac{1}{480} \left(c^2-1\right) t^5+\frac{(c+1) (c^2-15c
   +1) }{40320}t^7+O\left(t^9\right)$$

Comment: first of all thank you very much for helping me. Can us find exactly $c_0>0$ such that if we take the parameter $c\ge c_0$ we have $$\log\left(1-\frac{2f(t)}{f(t)+g(t)}\right)\ge \frac{1}{24} (c+1) t^3$$ for all $t\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}$?